# SyntaxError Python - for segment in segments.get('items', []):

Tags: python

I have a Python script which utilizes the Google Analytics API, and I am getting a syntax error in my `for` loop.

**Script**:

```
def get_segments():

    try:
      segments = analytics.management().segments().list().execute()

#   except TypeError, error:
        # Handle errors in constructing a query.
#       print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error

#   except HttpError, error:
        # Handle API errors.
#       print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %(error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))

    # Example #2:
    # The results of the list method are stored in the segments object.
    # The following code shows how to iterate through them.
    for segment in segments.get('items', []):
      print 'Segment Id         = %s' % segment.get('id')
      print 'Segment kind       = %s' % segment.get('kind')
      print 'Segment segmentId  = %s' % segment.get('segmentId')
      print 'Segment Name       = %s' % segment.get('name')
      print 'Segment Definition = %s' % segment.get('definition')
      if segment.get('created'):
        print 'Created    = %s' % segment.get('created')
        print 'Updated    = %s' % segment.get('updated')
      print
```

**Error**:

```
File "scripty.py", line 87
    for segment in segments.get('items', []):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why is there a `try` if you have no `except`?

Comment: You commented out all your `except` blocks. Python won't permit a `try` with no `except` or `finally`.

Comment: When the syntax error is not obvious where the caret points, start scanning back to previous lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is not in the for, but in the fact that you've commented out the except clauses that match the try. It's an error to have try with no except.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is not indented. Python separates blocks according to indentation. Apart from that, if you are using try, you will also have to use a catch block. Something like this should resolve the syntax error:

```
try:
  segments = analytics.management().segments().list().execute()
  for segment in segments.get('items', []):
    print 'Segment Id         = %s' % segment.get('id')
    print 'Segment kind       = %s' % segment.get('kind')
    print 'Segment segmentId  = %s' % segment.get('segmentId')
    print 'Segment Name       = %s' % segment.get('name')
    print 'Segment Definition = %s' % segment.get('definition')
    if segment.get('created'):
      print 'Created    = %s' % segment.get('created')
      print 'Updated    = %s' % segment.get('updated')
    print
except Exception as e:
  print "Exception Caught!"
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have a `try` block without an `except` or `finally` block. If the `for` loop is for when the `try` block fails, put it within an except block:

```
def get_segments():
    try:
        segments = analytics.management().segments().list().execute()
    except:
        for segment in segments.get('items', []):
            print 'Segment Id         = %s' % segment.get('id')
            print 'Segment kind       = %s' % segment.get('kind')
            print 'Segment segmentId  = %s' % segment.get('segmentId')
            print 'Segment Name       = %s' % segment.get('name')
            print 'Segment Definition = %s' % segment.get('definition')
            if segment.get('created'):
                print 'Created    = %s' % segment.get('created')
                print 'Updated    = %s' % segment.get('updated')
            print
```

In general, you should specify what type of exception you want to catch with the except block e.g. `except ValueError:` or `except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):` if there are multiple. If you want that block to be executed regardless of whether an error occurs or not, you should put it within `finally`.